# How to use a floating action button as notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, floating-action-button

I am creating an app using beacon technology.

The app recognises a beacon when in it's proximity, then queries the server to return all the other devices, that are near the recognised beacon.

What I want to do is, when the app receives the result from the server, a floating button should show up, as a form of notification.

I don't know how to dynamically create and show a floating button, upon receiving the data.

[This is the floating action button that I want to show as notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP3zF.png)

[image]

Comment: Simple, Add the Floating Button in the xml and set its visibility to `GONE` when you want to activate it just change the visibility to `VISIBLE`

Comment: Samuel is correct if you really wish to do what we understand.